# Separating request mappings for Web and REST requests in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have a Spring MVC web application. Now I want to expose my service as a web service using Spring REST. To do this I want to handle Web and REST requests based on URL values. Below I have tried the same with three controllers, MasterController, PatientController and PatientRESTController shown below. Methods have been skipped for brevity.

```
@Controller("/")
public class MasterController {

@RequestMapping("/web")
public ModelAndView webApplication(){
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/web/patient");
}

@RequestMapping("/rest")
public ModelAndView webService(){
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/rest/patient");
}
}
```

---

```
@Controller("/web/patient")
public class PatientController {

@GetMapping("")
public ModelAndView patientHome(){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("patienthome");
    return mv;
}
}
```

---

```
@RestController("/rest/patient")
public class PatientRESTController {

@GetMapping("")
public List getAllPatientsREST(){
    return patientService.findAll();
}
}
```

On starting my web application I am getting the error:

> Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map '/rest/patient' method 
>   public java.util.List PatientRESTController.getAllPatientsREST()
>   to {[],methods=[GET]}: There is already '/web/patient' bean method

How can I create different url mappings for my REST and Web application?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the the problem comes from the empty string in `@GetMapping("")` 
According to the thrown exception, it is not a relative mapping since in both cases, the resolved mapping by Spring is empty for your rest controllers :

> Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map '/rest/patient' method public
>   java.util.List PatientRESTController.getAllPatientsREST() to
>   {[],methods=[GET]}: There is already '/web/patient' bean method

You should specify a value in the getMapping annotation. You can try that or another thing :

```
@RestController
public class PatientRESTController {

 @GetMapping("/rest/patients")
 public List getAllPatientsREST(){
    return patientService.findAll();
 }
}
```

Personally, I would declare my `RestController` like that :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/patients")
public class PatientRESTController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAll(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     ...
    }
  }
```